# How to call the same API for N number of times using Retrofit and RXJava.I am using the following approach as of now

Tags: android, api, retrofit2, rx-android, rx-java2

Ok. So the API documentation says :

**Get up to 100 restaurants by changing the 'start' and 'count' parameters with the maximum value of count being
20.**
API LINK : https://developers.zomato.com/documentation#!/restaurant/search

This is the sample code :

```
restaurantList = new ArrayList<>();
    restaurantFinderAPI = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitClientAPI();
    restaurantScheduler = Schedulers.newThread();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 80; i += 20) {
        restaurantModelObservable = restaurantFinderAPI.getRestaraunts(city, entitytype, searchString, i, 20);

        restaurantModelObservable.subscribeOn(restaurantScheduler);
        restaurantModelObservable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        restaurantModelObservable.subscribe(new Observer<RestaurantModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                COUNT++;
                restaurantDisposable = d;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(RestaurantModel value) {
                restaurantList.addAll(value.getRestaurants());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                restaurantDisposable.dispose();
                onRestaurantSync.onRestaurantSyncFail();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                if (COUNT == 5) {
                    new ModifyTask().execute(restaurantList);
                    COUNT = 0;
                }
            }
        });
```

This is the Retrofit interface :

```
    String ZOMATO_ROOT_URL = "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/";

@GET("search")
@Headers({"Accept: application/json","user-key: 258f3e496748d15cb792bc554000d6b6"})
Observable<RestaurantModel> getRestaraunts(@Query("entity_id") int entityID,
                                           @Query("entity_type") String entity_type,
                                           @Query("q")String searchFor,
                                           @Query("start") int start,
                                           @Query("count") int count);
```

I making the call 5 times which is counted by the COUNT field, so it would give 100 results , by changing 'i'. Once I get 100 results, I start an asynctask for some processing on the dat. Is this a good way to call the same API multiple times. I am new to RXJava and I could not find a nice answer. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### A facility for threads to schedule tasks for future execution in a background thread. Tasks may be scheduled for one-time execution, or for repeated execution at regular intervals.

#### scheduleAtFixedRate

```
void scheduleAtFixedRate (TimerTask task, 
                long delay, 
                long period)
```

#### Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-rate execution, beginning after the specified delay. Subsequent executions take place at approximately regular intervals, separated by the specified period.

```
 Timer timer=  new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //Call Service Multiple times 
                //At EVery 6 seconds

            }
        },0,6000);
```

Comment: I think you got my question wrong. I want to call this api 5 times, one after the another. Each call gives me 20 results and i want to accumulate 100 results. What you are suggesting would call the api at specific interval, and i cant know how much time each api would take to return one call.

Answer (score 0):

I did this with the help of concat operator of RX. I simply made an observable from an array of offsets like {20,40,60,80} and made the call for each emission to the rest Api, and for each result, i added it to an arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe smth like this:

```
Disposable disposable = Observable.range(0, 5)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(i -> getRestaraunts(city, entitytype, searchString, i * 20, 20))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe();
```

Comment: Yes very similar to what I did.